# Find Parent Control By Type ->as String<-

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to find the parent of a UserControl using the string of the type.

For example, the method signature would look something like this:

```
DependencyObject FindParentControl(string type)
```

That would let me call it like this:

```
var parent = FindParentControl("MyRegion.MyView");
```

And it would traverse up the logical tree looking for a parent that has the passed in type.  If found it is returned (as an Object).  If not, null is returned.

All the examples I can see use generics and require the type.  Normally that is fantastic.  But in my situation, I have a view made by two other views (via a RegionManager) and there is no way to know who the parent/owner is.

Comment: `var parent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(this);` `if (parent.GetType().Name == type) {..}` or something. You know, I'm too tired and sleepy right now.

Comment: @HighCore - I tried that but it returns null.  Maybe at constructor time the tree is not setup yet?

Comment: yeah, you can't do that in the constructor of the UserControl. Try the `Loaded` event.

Comment: @HighCore - That worked!  If you want to sum all that up as an answer, I will accept it.